Pipelining throughput effect
There are two cpus with different pipelining stages

800ns 500ns 300ns 200ns | 4 stages
500ns 350ns 500ns 300ns 200ns  | 5 stages

Going from cpu1 to cpu2 will throughput increased or decreased ?
what will be %increase or %decrease in throughput?
I know that throughput will increase from cpu1 to cpu2 but I am unable to calculate mathematically what will be % increase in throughput. If all stages had same latency then calculations were gonna be pretty simple but I am unable to calculate for varying latency .
